Excluding headings inside a link
I need headings in a div to be the same size/ font/ color, but I want to exclude any headings inside links. I need anything inside the div to change - Any level of nesting.


#page-container h2 {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  color: #0F1111 !important;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

/*But I want to exclude any headings within links from this styling. */
<!--Example:-->
<div id="page-container">
  <h2> I want this to have styling changes</h2>
  <a> <h2> I don't want this to have styling changes because this is inside a tag </h2></a>
  <div>
    <h2> I want this to have styling changes</h2>
    <a> <h2> I don't want this to have styling changes because this is inside a tag </h2></a>
  </div>
</div>



How can I modify my CSS rule to exclude headings within 'a' tags? Changing HTML itself is not an option.

#page-container > h2, #page-container :not(a) > h2 would work here.

This question is similar to: Select first nested child in list but not subchilds. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DarkBee #page-container > h2 won't select the third h3 in the given example, because that is nested into an additional div.

Correct - Didn't read that far in, that's on me - Thanks for clarifying

I need anything inside the div to change. Any level of nesting. This has nothing to do with first/ nth child. I want all headings inside to change, but not inside 'a' tags. @C3roe - Your solution doesn't work for the reason you explained.

"I need anything inside the div to change. Any level of nesting" - Which was not stated in your initial question - If this is the case, you shouldn't use !important and reset the actual style when a h2 is residing in an a, .e.g a h2 { font-size: 12px; }

How about #page-container :is(h2):not(a h2) then?

@DarkBee - I cannot remove !important because there may be other existing CSS on the page that should be overridden, also do not want to define specific styling for 'a h2'.

@C3roe - That works. Thanks!

This works:
#page-container :is(h2):not(a h2)
Thanks @C3roe for answering in comments.

Like @C3roe says this code snippet works great i think. In the css code #page-container :not(a) > h2 excludes the a tags with h2


#page-container > h2,
#page-container :not(a) > h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #df1425;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
<div id="page-container">
      <h2>I want this to have styling changes</h2>
      <a>
        <h2>
          I don't want this to have styling changes because this is inside a tag
        </h2></a
      >
      <div>
        <h2>I want this to have styling changes</h2>
        <a>
          <h2>
            I don't want this to have styling changes because this is inside a
            tag
          </h2></a
        >
      </div>




I think this would not work if h2 is not a direct child of a.
